# Does anyone have a geological map 1 / 1 000 000 or 1 / 50k of Morocco in HD?

Tags: mapping

I am having a problem reading in my low version map.
Besides, any tips on where I can find "free" maps?

Thank you!

Comment: One site I've always found useful to view topo is https://en-us.topographic-map.com/maps/jlml/Morocco/  Comparing it to some of the 1:500000 maps, it seems to have at least similar resolution, and extends through the whole country.  Digging into it more, the legal notice links to a [paper](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/2017GL072874) suggesting it is made using multi-spaceborne data, coming to 3 min resolution (~90 m at the Equator, which should be about 78 m in Morocco). Perhaps search related to the paper can lead you to a place you could acquire that data directly?

Answer (score 3):

It is not so evident if you look for the big picture (grammar school's project?), or detail and specific region.  Because even today, the geological mapping of Morocco is not complete ([gouvernmental reference](https://www.mem.gov.ma/en/Pages/secteur.aspx?e=8)), the 19 already digitized geological maps about Morocco  on [gallica.fr](https://gallica.bnf.fr/services/engine/search/sru?operation=searchRetrieve&version=1.2&startRecord=0&maximumRecords=15&page=1&query=(gallica%20all%20%22maroc%20geologie%22)&filter=dc.type%20all%20%22carte%22) may be an interesting entry for you.  The GUI interface is more helpful for books, than for maps (selection of the page, export as .pdf / .jpeg), but there is a zoom and pan option to see some details on the maps pretty well.

E.g., a more general one by Brumnich (1936, 1:500'000) [here](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/btv1b53121384p/f1.item.r=maroc%20geologie%20carte.zoom), or one with stratigraphic / petrographic details about central Morocco by Termier (1932, 1:200'000) [here](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/btv1b530668257/f1.item.r=maroc%20geologie.zoom).

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to find one from 85's but the one you gave from 36's in HD will help me to read the locations.